# Finding longer base and the area of a scalene trapezoid

Tags: geometry

Given scalene trapezoid with the following characteristics:

- $c = DC = 2$ cm (shorter base)
- $b = BC = 8$ cm (leg)
- $d = AD = 5$ cm (leg)
- $\cos \angle ABC = 1/7$

Find $AB = a$ (longer base) and $S$ (area of the trapezoid).

[image]

### What I know for sure

$S = 1/2 \times ((a + c) \times h)$

$P = a + b + c + d$

$\alpha + \delta = \beta + \gamma = 180°$

$h = d \sin \alpha = b \sin \beta$

### My attempt

Given $\cos \angle ABC = 1/7$, I believe I have to use the cosine theorem.

$BD = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + 2ab \cos(B)}$

$AC = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos(B)}$

We don't know $BD$, $AC$ and $a$ and I'm kinda stuck.

By looking at the formulas above, we could probably find the height of the trapezoid using $h = d \sin \alpha = b \sin \beta$. We have $b$ and $\cos \beta$. However, we need $\sin$, not the $\cos$, which stomps me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If perp from $C$ to $AB$ meets at $G$, $ \displaystyle BG = b \cos \beta$

Applying Pythagoras, $h = CG = \sqrt{b^2 - BG^2}$

If perp from $D$ to $AB$ meets at $H$ then,

$AH = \sqrt{d^2 - h^2}$

$ \displaystyle AB = AH + GH + BG~$ and $GH = CD = c$

The only problem is that once you find $h$, you realize $h \gt d$ which is not possible.  So the given measurements are wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! BG = 8 * 1/7 = 8/7. h = CG = (32 * sqrt(3)) / 7. Is that result normal? It would be better if you include the calculations because I'm afraid of the numbers I receive

Comment: There is a problem with the given measures. What you found for $h$ is correct and given it is a trapezoid $d$ should be equal to or bigger than $h$ but it is not.